# getting value between alt of img tag

Tags: php, regex

how can I get value between alt tag of image using regular expression
e.g I have `<img class="sprite-ratings" alt="3 of 5 stars" src="http://c1.tacdn.com/img2/x.gif">`
now I want 3 of 5 stars
I want it on server side.
can anyone help me?

Comment: i think you can get like this ".$value."

Comment: i need via regelar expression

Comment: The alt tag is ment for an alternative text when the image isn't there or a blind human being is trying to surf on your website. Its better to use the data tag. For example data-stars="3 of 5".

Answer (score 10):

This `regex` will match: `'/<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*>/'`

```
preg_match('/<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*>/',$str,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

Output:

```
3 of 5 stars
```

Explanation:

```
<img  # Match the literal string 
.*?   # Match anything after (non-greedy)
alt=" # Upto the literal string
(.*?) # Capture everything after
"     # Upto the literal
.*>   # Match everything else up to the closing >
```

Comment: Yeah It is working now. Thank you @sudo_O. It's really a big help for me.

Comment: +1, though it's nicer form to use "([^"]*)" to match double quoted enclosures :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$res = preg_match("/<img[^>]+alt=\"([^>]*)\"[^>]*>/iU", $yourstring, $matches);
if ($res) {
    echo "the alternative text is: " . $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: Yeah It is working now. Thank you @Kaii. It's really a big help for me.